# Publishing C# project from Visual Studio 2015 invalid manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, monogame

My project runs fine within Visual Studio, but when I publish it and try to run setup.exe for it on the same dev computer, I get an error:

```
    + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Game/Application%20Files/F1_1_0_0_9/F1.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
        -HRESULT:   0x8007001f
         Start line:    0
         Start column:  0
         Host file:     
    + A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
```

I have tried disabling signing of ClickOnce manifests, that just gives me a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a million things like signing the manifest differently, deleting/adding dpi-aware flags to the manifest, using different versions of .NET, etc, I managed to solve it just by deleting the manifest file from my solution.  Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Well probably your project not doing the thing that you want in manifest now such as creating desktop shortcut etc. Mostly these are optional features so that you will not have a problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).